# "ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set" between i.MX6 and VM Ubuntu

Tags: android, adb

I'm having a problem using adb between an i.MX6 on Android and my PC with an Ubuntu VM .
When I want to push a file to the i.MX6, I get:

```
adb: error: failed to get feature set: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

I only have access to command line on i.MX6 side.
I saw some topics which talk about this problem but is was between Android Studio and an Android smartphone.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is that both i.MX6 and Ubuntu VM does not have the right keys.

First start the adb server on your Ubuntu VM:

`adb start-server`

`adbkey` and `adbkey.pub` files are generated and stored in the `~/.android/` directory on my Ubuntu VM.

So we can now go to this directory and copy the content of the `adbkey.pub` file.

Then we can edit the public key file on our device (i.MX6) and paste it.
This file is located in `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` and can be modified manually using vi.

We can now run the daemon on the i.MX6 with the following commands:

`stop adbd`

`setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555`

`start adbd`

And then connect from the Linux VM (replacing x.x.x.x with the IP address of our device):

`adb connect x.x.x.x`